# Turn off TV via HDMI?

Tags: television, hdmi

I'm working on a set-top-box, and was wondering if the HDMI standard includes the possibility of turning off the TV screen through the device that it is connected to?
Not just stopping the HDMI output, but completely shutting down the screen.

I've looked through the list of HDMI-CEC commands, but not sure if this feature fits the description of "Deck Control".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is in the HDMI CEC
https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/blob/master/src/libcec/implementations/CECCommandHandler.cpp#L763

```
// CEC_USER_CONTROL_CODE_POWER and CEC_USER_CONTROL_CODE_POWER_TOGGLE_FUNCTION operate as a toggle
// assume CEC_USER_CONTROL_CODE_POWER_ON_FUNCTION does not
```

> Disclaimer: Github [libcec repository](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec) layout is subject to changes,
>   look for the `CECCommandHandler.cpp` file

Comment: Thank you very much! Just in case someone else wanted to have a look, the line is 683.

Comment: link not available